# how do Post method in axios?

Tags: reactjs

[Image that i want to save in post url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muoEw.png)

**Code**

```
     click=(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("post method used",this.state);
            axios.post('http://localhost:9763/api/notify?ObjectID=23454&Status=Play',
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    },
                    auth: {
                        username: 'admin',
                        password: 'password'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                      console.log("post",response.data);
                     console.log(typeof response.data);
    
                }).catch(error => {
                    this.setState({ error: 'unable to fetch URL' });
                    console.log(error.response);
                });
        }
        <ul className="nav nav-treeview">
//already fetching data from get method
                                                {Data.map((val) => {
                                                    
                                                    return (
                                                        <li key={val} style={{ color: "white" }} onClick={this.click}><a href="/SecondPlaylist">{val}</a></li>                                                  
    
                                                    )
    
                                                })
                                                }
                                            </ul>
```

post method in axios.
I am fetching the data from another URL and want that data save to another URL, when I click on them i.e rundown1,rundown2,rundown3,rundown4 in json format. I am not able to send them in another URL if I click them. plz help

Comment: What do you mean with "not able to send them in another URL"?

Comment: I mean i not able to send data "rundown1" if I click for save in json file url